# Craft Commerce not outputting € symbol

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Within Settings, the cart currency is set to Euros. But when I use:

```
{{ product.defaultVariant.price | currency(cart.currency) }}
```

The output is:

```
¤150.49
```

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Is this perhaps related to the font you are using to show the currency in front-end templates? Have you tried using different fonts to see if the problem persists?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm just using Arial and it's in the page source.

Comment: What does `cart.currency` return? Looking through the code, the Twig `currency` filter ultimately uses Yii's `CNumberFormatter` class. This uses the symbol you are seeing as a default placeholder for the currency symbol if one cannot be determined from the value of the `$currency` parameter passed to it. See here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberFormatter#format-detail This would indicate that the value of `cart.currency` is not as expected. How is this being set?

Comment: Good point. That was the problem. I'd not included {% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %} anywhere so the cart was missing. Do you want to add that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: Great! I've added is as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `cart.currency` return?

The Twig `currency` filter ultimately uses Yii's [`CNumberFormatter`](http://yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberFormatter#format-detail) class. This uses the symbol you are seeing as a default placeholder for the currency symbol if one cannot be determined from the value of the `$currency` parameter passed to it. This would indicate that the value of `cart.currency` is not as expected. You'll need to make sure that the `cart` variable is being set correctly in your template, then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

As [Steve mentions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16267/craft-commerce-not-outputting-%E2%82%AC-symbol#comment22613_16267), most likely this is because the font you are using on the front-end of your site doesn't know how to display the € symbol.

I just tested on a fresh Craft/Commerce install on OSX/Chrome and the default Commerce templates display € as expected.

Comment: See reply to Steve above.

Comment: Once again, I bow to @SteveRowling's superior knowledge.